WPF - TabControl messes DataGrid bindings
I having 2 datagrids inside a TabControl. Tabs are 'Files' and 'Symbols'
As I click on the 'Symbols' tab and get back to the 'Files' tab, the 'Files' DataGrid gets displayed with the proper template but with the 'Symbols' data
... like if bindings were swapped between datagrids as I switch tabs
As a workaround I forced ItemSource of the displayed datagrid when a different tab is switched, but it disconnects row items
here is the template
<TabControl Grid.Row="1" x:Name="tabsControl" SelectionChanged="OnTabChanged_TabsControl">
 
    <TabItem x:Name="filesTab">
        <TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="{DynamicResource FilesTabIcon}" Width="19" Height="19"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Files" Margin="4,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <!-- data -->
            <DataGrid x:Name="filesDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Files}" Style="{DynamicResource SearchDataGrid}" Sorting="OnDataSort_Files" SelectionMode="Single" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10" IsReadOnly="True" Visibility="Collapsed">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name" Width="auto" SortMemberPath="Name">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                    <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" Width="16" Height="16" Margin="0,0,4,0"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MouseLeftButtonDown="OnClick_FilesItem"/>
                                </StackPanel>                                      
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Path" Width="*" SortMemberPath="Path">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Button Click="OnClick_FileLink" ToolTip="Copy path to clipboard" Height="16" Width="25" Padding="0,-2,0,0" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle}">
                                        <Image Source="{DynamicResource LinkImageResource}" Width="19" Height="19" Margin="0"/>
                                    </Button>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path}" Margin="4,0,0,0" MouseLeftButtonDown="OnClick_FilesItem"/>
                                </StackPanel>                                        
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>                      
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>
    </TabItem>

    <TabItem x:Name="symbolsTab">
        <TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="{DynamicResource SymbolsTabIcon}" Width="19" Height="19"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Symbols" Margin="4,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <!-- data -->
            <DataGrid x:Name="symbolsDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Symbols}" Style="{DynamicResource SearchDataGrid}" Sorting="OnDataSort_Symbols" SelectionMode="Single" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10" IsReadOnly="True" Visibility="Collapsed">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="auto" SortMemberPath="Name"/>

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name" Width="auto" SortMemberPath="Name">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                    <Button Click="OnClick_SymbolLink" ToolTip="Copy path to clipboard" Height="16" Width="25" Padding="0,-2,0,0" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle}">
                                        <Image Source="{DynamicResource LinkImageResource}" Width="19" Height="19" Margin="0"/>
                                    </Button>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="4,0,0,0"  MouseLeftButtonDown="OnClick_SymbolsItem"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>
    </TabItem>

</TabControl>

in the code behind I use these properties
public partial class MyControl : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private List<SearchDataItem> _files = null;
   public List<SearchDataItem> Files
   {
       get { return _files; }
       set
       {
           if (_files != value)
           {
               _files = value;
               OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Files));
           }
       }
   }

   private List<SearchDataItem> _symbols = null;
   public List<SearchDataItem> Symbols
   {
       get { return _symbols; }
       set
       {
           if (_symbols != value)
           {
               _symbols = value;
               OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Symbols));
           }
       }
   }

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
   protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
   {
       PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }

   public FilesSearchControl()
   {
       this.InitializeComponent();
       DataContext = this;  // make sure the DC is set to this object
   }

   ...
}

Thanks for helping me out on this

In controls, or on DependencyObject in general, bindable or animatable properties should be dependency properties. Controls don't implement INotifyPropertyChanged. This doesn't allow to assign bindings (binding target) or animations to such simple CLR properties. Additionally depdency properties are faster. INotifyPropertyChanged is for types that don't extend DependencyObject.

DataContext = this;  is also considered bad practice as it will break data binding from the client. Better name your UserControl and use Binding.ElementName to use the UserControl as binding source.

@BionicCode not sure I understand what you mean, can you give an example ?

Can you please post a minimal reproducible example? It must contain every line of code that is required to reproduce the behavior. If a line of code, a resource like a Style is not required then remove them and all their references. If the Style is required to reproduce it then show the style. The described behavior is not normal. But we can only review if you give us somewthing reasonable to review.

"Changing Tabs" fires the Loaded event. Every time. If you don't take measures to preserve / restore state, then you will have "unpredictable" results.
